# How parse dynamic element attribute and their values in XML using XPATH

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Trying to parse XML with xpath and create map between ELEMENT elementId id and their group id list as in the picture below

```
<ITEM type="DTD" sub_type="T_AAAAAA">
  <ELEMENT elementId="4" print="no" mail="no" tabSortIndex="0">
    <ADD_TO_HOME_PAGE_2>
      <PARAM name="name" value="ADD_TO_HOMEPAGE_2_TEXT" />
    </ADD_TO_HOME_PAGE_2>
  </ELEMENT>
  <ELEMENT tabId="1" elementId="7">
    <EDITOR_FIELD>
      <PARAM name="name" value="E_E1" />
    </EDITOR_FIELD>
    <GROUPS mode="whitelist">
      <GROUP id="0" />
      <GROUP id="1" />
      <GROUP id="5" />
    </GROUPS>
  </ELEMENT>
  <ELEMENT elementId="8" tabId="1" mail="no">
    <PHONE>
      <PARAM name="name" value="E_F1" />
      <PARAM name="display_as_link" value="no" />
    </PHONE>
    <GROUPS mode="whitelist">
      <GROUP id="1" />
      <GROUP id="16" />
    </GROUPS>
  </ELEMENT>
</ITEM>
```

The element id is dynamic and changed I've tried this

```
 "//ELEMENT[@elementId>0]/text()/GROUPS/GROUP[@id]/text()"
```

but it gives me null

Basically I want to map between `[@elementId>0]` to array of `/GROUPS/GROUP[@id]`

example for output

for element 7 => `{"7" : [0,1,2,5]}`

for element 8 => `{"8" : [1,16]}`

P.S - I use `org.apache.xpath.CachedXPathAPI` library in JAVA

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve but any attempt like `//ELEMENT[@elementId>0]/text()/GROUPS` doesn't make sense, text nodes (selected with `text()`) are always leaf nodes so they never have any child nodes like `text()/GROUPS` tries to select.

Comment: thanks @Martin Honnen, I know the syntax not correct. Im trying to get  for example in elementId="8" , the actual number 8 and all ids under GROUPS means id="1" and 16".  Also for all other elements(create kind of map) it can be done later by code

Comment: Are you open to using other libraries such as Jsoup?

Comment: no , only org.apache.xpath.CachedXPathAPI

Comment: and also groovy.util.XmlParser. example: new XmlParser().parseText(doc)

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for requires XPath 2.0 functionality.
If you really want to realize this in one XPath 2.0 expression, the solution is

```
string-join(for $item in /ITEM/ELEMENT[@elementId>0] return concat('{&quot;',$item/@elementId,'&quot; : [', string-join(for $grp in $item/GROUPS/GROUP return $grp/@id,', '),']}'),'&#xa;')
```

And its output is

```
{"4" : []}
{"7" : [0, 1, 5]}
{"8" : [1, 16]}
```

With XPath version 1.0 (supported by Java) you'd have to split that expression into several sub-queries/loops.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you talk about "mapping" that you have a particular element identifier in mind and you want to query the document and retrieve the identifiers of groups that corresponding to the element.

In this example I'm querying for the identifiers of groups belonging to element 7.

```xml
//ELEMENT[@elementId='7']/GROUPS/GROUP/@id
```

This means:

Create the set of every `ELEMENT` in the document, filter the set to include only those nodes which have an `elementId` attribute equal to `7`, then find the `GROUPS` child elements of that set of `ELEMENT` nodes, the `GROUP` child elements of those `GROUPS` elements, and finally the `id` attributes of those `GROUP` elements.

Comment: But maybe you want a query which returns an actual mapping, e.g. as a JSON object? It's not clear. Note that the Apache API you are using supports XPath 1 in which there is no "array" data type, and no "map" data type. To return a map you would need to upgrade to an XPath 3.1 interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch from the Apache library to the Saxon library which supports XPath 3.1, you can define and execute an XPath whose return value is a map, containing keys which are the `ELEMENT` identifiers, and whose corresponding values are arrays of `GROUP` identifiers:

```xml
map:merge(
   //ELEMENT/map:entry(
      @elementId/string(), 
      array{GROUPS/GROUP/@id/string()}
   )
)
```

Read the above expression as:
For every `ELEMENT` in the document, call the `map:entry` function to create a map with a single key equal to the string value of the `ELEMENT`'s `elementId` attribute, and a value equal to an array containing the string values of the `ELEMENT`'s `GROUPS/GROUP/@id` attributes, and then merge these maps into a single map.

This data structure will be returned to you back in Java-land as a Java `Map` whose keys are `String` objects and whose values are arrays of `String` objects. i.e.

```
{
  "4": [],
  "7": [
    "0",
    "1",
    "5"
  ],
  "8": [
    "1",
    "16"
  ]
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/?xpath=map%3Amerge%28%2F%2FELEMENT%2Fmap%3Aentry%28%40elementId%2Fstring%28%29%2C%20array%7BGROUPS%2FGROUP%2F%40id%2Fstring%28%29%7D%29%29&input=%3CITEM%20type%3D%22DTD%22%20sub_type%3D%22T_AAAAAA%22%3E%0A%20%20%3CELEMENT%20elementId%3D%224%22%20print%3D%22no%22%20mail%3D%22no%22%20tabSortIndex%3D%220%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CADD_TO_HOME_PAGE_2%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPARAM%20name%3D%22name%22%20value%3D%22ADD_TO_HOMEPAGE_2_TEXT%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FADD_TO_HOME_PAGE_2%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FELEMENT%3E%0A%20%20%3CELEMENT%20tabId%3D%221%22%20elementId%3D%227%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CEDITOR_FIELD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPARAM%20name%3D%22name%22%20value%3D%22E_E1%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEDITOR_FIELD%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CGROUPS%20mode%3D%22whitelist%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CGROUP%20id%3D%220%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CGROUP%20id%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CGROUP%20id%3D%225%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FGROUPS%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FELEMENT%3E%0A%20%20%3CELEMENT%20elementId%3D%228%22%20tabId%3D%221%22%20mail%3D%22no%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CPHONE%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPARAM%20name%3D%22name%22%20value%3D%22E_F1%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPARAM%20name%3D%22display_as_link%22%20value%3D%22no%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FPHONE%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CGROUPS%20mode%3D%22whitelist%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CGROUP%20id%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CGROUP%20id%3D%2216%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FGROUPS%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FELEMENT%3E%0A%3C%2FITEM%3E%0A&input-type=XML) in the form of an XSLT fiddle